# How to prevent ad blocker on my site's routes?

Tags: reactjs, http, endpoint, adblock

In my React web app, which is a content management system, I have an "Advertisers" screen where users can handle an "Advertiser" entity.

This screen interacts with endpoints on my own server (same domain) which contains the word "advertiser", e.g.

`GET <domain>/advertiser/31`
or
`GET <domain>/info?advertisers`

The problems is that ad blockers are recognizing my routes as harmful and block requests to these routes.

Is there a way to overcome it except for renaming my endpoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer**

For an internal application, have your users disable ad-blocker browser plugins for your website's domain. For an public facing website, the most practical approach is to rename `<domain>/advertiser/31` to something like `<domain>/vendor/31`.

**Ad-blocker Filters By URL Pattern**

Assuming your React Content Management System is only used within a corporate intranet, you should have some control over your users' environment. Explicitly include instructions to whitelist your domain in ad-blocking software.

An ad-blocker has a few mechanism to filter advertisements, and one of it is URL pattern matching. Take for example the popular advertisement filter list [EasyList](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt). You can see patterns such as `/advertises/*`. If your URL matches any of these patterns, they will be blocked.